# Where can I print photo albums in the UK?

Tags: service-recommendation, printed-album

Could someone recommend a service to print photo albums (in the UK)? I tried one popular company (that also has a chain of pharmacies), but their website is so full of bugs that it's almost not possible to create the album online.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Photobox](http://www.photobox.co.uk/) I have not used them to print albums but only have positive experiences for other types of printing.

Comment: same experience; quick turnaround

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Albelli](http://www.albelli.co.uk/) in the past with good results. They provide a software package that lets you easily create an album, either via templates or from scratch, and order straight from there. They are based in the Netherlands, but ship using UK rates, fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1):

We've used [My Publisher](http://www.mypublisher.uk.com/products/photobooks) in the past to create Photo books.  We started using the site, because they give a discount to Costco members but I think it's open to anybody.

You download the software package, which comes with a variety of different templates (different numbers of pictures on the pages, pages with just pictures, pages with text).  The software has some basic image manipulation (rotation, cropping etc) and allows you to work off line, before uploading the finished book.

They do a variety of different print formats (hard and soft cover), although we've only really used the soft cover options to create story books for my son, but the quality was good and they've lasted with a 5 year old thumbing his way through them.